# CSS animation in webkit goes to zero before auto

Tags: javascript, css, animation, webkit

I am working on a project in which I need to animate a div to a specified height, but then animate set its `height` to `auto`. Strangely, when the div's height is set to `auto`, the height is animated to height, and then jumps to auto. I have observed this behavior in Safari and Chrome.

Here is my testing code:

HTML:

```
<div id="a" style="height:0px;"><div style="height:100px;"></div></div>
```

CSS:

```
#a{
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all .5s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all .5s ease-out;
    transition: all .5s ease-out;
    width:100px;
    background:blue;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
window.setTimeout(function(){
    document.getElementById("a").style.height = "100px";
}, 10);

window.setTimeout(function(){
    //The auto height will be 100px. The div will already be at this... But it animates to 0px and then goes to auto. Strange right!?!?
    document.getElementById("a").style.height = "auto";
}, 2000);
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Progo/vqkpuzte/)**

**How can I fix this?** Thank you. *If you down vote, please tell me why so I can improve this question.*

Answer (score 1):

You unfortunately can't animate to auto at this point in time using CSS3 animations. An alternative would be to try animating the `transform` property and going from `transform: scale(0)` to `transform: scale(1)`, but you won't have the desired effect. It' a tricky subject and a lot of peeps have tried to deal with it and hack around it!

Comment: I am not animating to auto. I am already at the ago value, just in pixels. I just want to change that to `auto`. There would be no animation. Try my example in firefox, it works as desired.